# Showing contour integral $\int_{C_R}\frac{e^{st}}{\sqrt{s}}\,ds$ goes to $0$

Tags: complex-analysis, laplace-transform, contour-integration

I was working on a question similar to this: [Special Laplace Inversion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/313286/special-laplace-inversion), and reading through the solution I couldn't figure out how to justify that the integral along the circular arcs goes to $0$ as $R\rightarrow\infty$ and $r\rightarrow0$. I tried to parameterise as $p=c+Re^{i\theta}$, but then in the integral $\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}e^{pt}p^{-\frac{1}{2}} \text{d}p$, there ends up being a term $\log|c+Re^{i\theta}|$, which doesnt really simplify. Is there a better approach to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We cut the plane from $0$ to $-\infty$ along the non-positive real axis.  The parameterization of the circular arc is $s=Re^{i\theta}$, where $-\pi \theta\le \pi$.   Then, we see that

Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{R\to \infty}\int_{C_R}\frac{e^{st}}{\sqrt{s}}\,ds&=\lim_{R\to \infty}\int_{\pi/2-\arctan(a/R)}^{\pi^-}\frac{e^{Re^{i\theta}t}}{\sqrt{R}e^{i\theta/2}}\,iRe^{i\theta}\,d\theta\\\\
&+\lim_{R\to \infty}\int_{-\pi^+}^{-\pi/2+\arctan(a/R)}\frac{e^{Re^{i\theta}t}}{\sqrt{R}e^{i\theta/2}}\,iRe^{i\theta}\,d\theta\\\\
&=\lim_{R\to \infty}2i\sqrt{R} \int_{\pi/2-\arctan(a/R)}^{\pi^-} e^{R\cos(\theta t)}\cos\left(R\sin(\theta)t+\theta/2\right)\,d\theta\tag1
\end{align}$$

---

Next, we have the estimates for the integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$.

$$\begin{align}
\left|2i\sqrt{R}\int_{\pi/2-\arctan(a/R)}^{\pi^-}e^{R\cos(\theta)t}e^{i(R\sin(\theta)t+\theta/2)}\,d\theta\right|&\le 2\sqrt{R}\int_{\pi/2-\arctan(a/R)}^{\pi^-}e^{R\cos(\theta)t}\,d\theta\\\\
&=2\sqrt{R}\int_{-\arctan(a/R)}^{\pi/2} e^{-R\sin(\theta)t}\,d\theta\\\\
&\le 2\sqrt{R}\int_{-\arctan(a/R)}^0e^{-R\sin(\theta)t}\,d\theta\\\\
&+2\sqrt{R}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}e^{-R\sin(\theta)t}\,d\theta\\\\
&\le2\sqrt{R}\int_{-\arctan(a/R)}^0e^{-R\theta t}\,d\theta\\\\
&+2\sqrt{R}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}e^{-R2\theta t/\pi}\,d\theta\\\\
&=\frac{2\left(e^{R\arctan(a/R)t}-1\right)}{\sqrt{R}t}\\\\
&+\frac{\pi\left(1-e^{-Rt}\right)}{\sqrt{R}t}\tag 2
\end{align}$$

---

Note that $\lim_{R\to \infty}R\arctan(a/R)=a$.

Therefore, as $R\to \infty$, the terms on the right-hand side of $(2)$ approach $0$ and we assert that

> $$\lim_{R\to \infty}\int_{C_R}\frac{e^{st}}{\sqrt{s}}\,ds=0$$

as was to be shown.

Comment: I was under the impression that the contour looked like this:
https://www.physicsforums.com/attachments/contour-jpg.37677/
And if this is the case, then the way you have defined $\theta$ doesn't work because of the branch cut, right?

Comment: Well, the detour won't affect the result.  We can integrate from $\pi/2 -\arctan(a/R)$ to $\pi-\epsilon$ and from $\pi+\epsilon$ to $3\pi/2+\arctan(a/R)$.

Comment: And then if I follow similar steps, each integral will go to 0 individually?

Comment: Yes, thats correct

Comment: For the part which says $$\left|\text{RHS of }(1)\right|\le \sqrt{R}\int_{-\arctan(a/R)}^{\pi+\arctan(a/R)}e^{R\cos(\theta)t}\,d\theta\\\\
=2\sqrt{R}\int_{-\arctan(a/R)}^{\pi/2} e^{-R\sin(\theta)t}\,d\theta\\\\$$
Line 1: I don't understand why the limits change - have you done $\theta\rightarrow\theta-\frac{\pi}{2}$? If so, shouldn't $\cos(\theta)\rightarrow\sin(\theta)$? It appears that for the rest of if, you have used $\left|\int \text{.}d\theta\right|\le\int\left|\text{.}\right|d\theta$, which I understand.

Comment: Continuation of above comment:
Line 2: Again the limits change, however if using $\theta\rightarrow\theta-\frac{\pi}{2}$ again, then I don't see where the negative sign comes in, which is crucial for the question.

Comment: @JohnDoe John, I've edited to account for the branch cut along the non-positive real axis.  As for the transformation, we let $\theta \to \theta +\pi/2$.  Then, $\cos(\theta)\to -\sin(\theta)$ and the integration limits transform from $\int_{\pi/2+\arctan(a/R)}^{\pi^-}\,d\theta$ to $\int_{-\arctan(a/R)}^{\pi/2}\,d\theta$.

Comment: Ah yes, I see my mistake! The limits were transforming by $-\pi/2$ which I thought would mean the variable transformed as $\theta \rightarrow \theta -
 \pi/2$, when in fact its the other way around. Thanks very much.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure. -Mark